# Should I Expect the Forward("my.username@gmail.com") Route to Email Me?

Tags: mailgun

I have my catch_all() set to forward("my.username@gmail.com"). I expected that any emails caught by this route would be forwarded to my email address as actual emails, but I never received them. The mailgun logs state that the message was routed, accepted, and delivered successfully.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being gmail... I was sending my test messages from my gmail account and had the forward setup to return to my gmail. Gmail filters out loopbacks. Sending the test message from a different account yielded the expected results

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, setting the catch_all and forward filters and actions does just that!

Did you set up the MX records for your domain properly? If not, that might be the issue (check Domains in the control panel)

Check the logs at https://mailgun.com/cp/log to debug the issue!

Best

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem ended up being gmail... I was sending my test messages from my gmail account and had the forward setup to return to my gmail. Gmail filters out loopbacks. Sending the test message from a different account yielded the expected results.